# Change Color Of Form Labels

Tags: macos, swiftui

How do I change the color of form labels in SwiftUI?

For example, `Kundennummer` should be gray, but `1033` should be white.

[image]

I have 3 different forms:

```
// "Kundennummer"
TextField("Kundennummer", text: $customerNumber)

// "Anrede"
Picker("Anrede", selection: $previewIndex) {
    ForEach(0 ..< previewOptions.count) {
        Text(self.previewOptions[$0])
    }
}

// Section "Kontakt"
Section(header: Text("Kontakt")) {
    TextField("Telefon", text: $phone)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements have many different initialisers. You're currently using the form that takes a string as the first argument and creates a `Text` view using that string. But there are other forms that let you use a view block to create your own form label - and that label can be any SwiftUI view, including a `Text` with its colour changed from the default.

For example, in place of

```swift
TextField("Kundennummer", text: $customerNumber)
```

you could use

```swift
TextField(text: $customerNumber) {
  Text("Kundennummer")
    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
}
```

And for pickers, you'd need something like:

```swift
Picker(selection: $previewIndex) {
  ForEach(0 ..< previewOptions.count) {
    Text(self.previewOptions[$0])
  }
} label: {
  Text("Anrede")
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I only couldn't figure it out how to do it with the `Picker`. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @Nikolass - have updated with an example for Picker.